# Intelligent coalesce

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

I have a table with some basic address data:

[image: table structure]

If Street and Postcode/Town are filled, I want Street and Postcode/Town separated by comma.

`select Concat(coalesce(Street,''),", ", coalesce(Postcode,'')," ",coalesce(Town,'')) from adresses`

If street is not available, I would like to have just the postcode and town separated by a blank, if even the post code is missing I want just the name (if just postcode is missing, I'd like to have "Street, Town")

How can I design the query so that it considers what is available and where comma and blank need to be put?

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN ... END` construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this with with the built-in `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(', ', Street, Postcode, Town)
from adresses;
```

If any of the arguments are `NULL` (except the separator), then `concat_ws()`, simply skips that string and the associated separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    (case when
        street is not null
        and postcode is not null
        and town is not null
    then concat(street,', ',postcode,', ',town)
    when 
        street is null
        and postcode is not null
        and town is not null
    then concat(postcode,' ',town)
    when
        street is null
        and postcode is null
        and town is not null
    then town
    else 'N/A'
    end) myAddress
from address
```

You may have to check for the empty string depending on your data i.e.

`when street is not null and street <> ''`

Answer (score 0):

select street||','||town||','||coalesce(postcode,null,'') from LCI_DW_views.UACI_TRMTRULEINV where offername like '%644970%'